# Hangfire .net core console Dependency Injection

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, hangfire

I have a project with this structure

- `AdventureWorks.Web` <- .NET Core web project (Services, Viewmodels, DataContext, Controller Views, etc )
- `AdventureWorks.Console` <- .NET Core console app (hangfire config server)
- `AdventureWorks.Model` <- just pure POCO model classes

I am trying to run the Hangfire server in a separate process (`AdventureWorks.Console`)
[https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/processing-jobs-in-console-app.html]

Processing jobs in a console application.

I added a reference to `AdventureWorks.Web` to the `AdventureWorks.Console` - this way the Hangfire server would execute the code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("Connection");

    using (var server = new BackgroundJobServer())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hangfire Server started. Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

In the web project I'm registering my services in the `Startup` class

```
services.AddTransient<IDepartmentServices, DepartmentServices>();
```

The constructor has a parameter witch is auto injected

```
private readonly AdventureWorksDataContext db;

    public DepartmentServices(AdventureWorksDataContext _db)
    {
        db = _db;
    }
```

In the controller the services are injected

```
private readonly IDepartmentServices Service;

    public DepartmentsController(IDepartmentServices service)
    {
        Service = service;
    }
```

In one method in the controller when the user click the button "create report" the method enqueue a job to create a report

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<**IDepartmentService**>((serv) => serv.CrearReport(data));
```

So far so good.

I can see in the dashboard the job created but it fails to execute

> System.MissingMethodException Cannot create an instance of an interface.

which is obvious so my first question is

- How create a job respecting the dependency injection? I'm trying to follow the instruction here [https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/passing-dependencies.html] but I don't see nothing about the dependency which is injected my best guest hangfire doesn't work with dependency injecting

So to continue I change the interface with the class

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue<DepartmentService>((serv) => serv.CrearReport(data));
```

so far so good the job is created. But it fails with the error

> System.MissingMethodException
>   No parameterless constructor defined for this object

which is obvious so my second question is

- how do I pass the parameter `datacontext` to hangfire server? My best guess is I can't because hangfire server is using an Activator which wants an empty constructor

So to continue I followed the instructions here [https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/passing-dependencies.html]

I created an empty constructor

```
public EmployeeService()
        :this(new AdventureWorksDataContext())
    {

    }
```

and i need add an empty constructor to the datacontext

```
public AdventureWorksDataContext()
    {

    }
```

but now i need to override the "OnConfigure" method

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("????");<--connectionstring???
    }
```

so my question is how do i get the connectionstring from the appsettings.json my best guest i cant 
ignoring this problem i add the direct connection

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=AdventureWorks2017;Trusted_Connection=True;");
```

this way the job is completed correct

but this solution i think is bad maybe the project structure is bad or how the dependency injection works with hangfire if is running in a separete process, how IoC works en hangfire server console

some one point me a better solution how structure the project

sorry for my English i dont't speak

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-core-applications.html. In the past I was using Hangfire.AutoFac nuget using a custom JobActivator suioted for that given DI framework.

A lot has changed, check out: https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/using-ioc-containers.html and (this should work) https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-core-applications.html

--- what I had:

So actually you need to add some hangfire related object to the container. I used AutoFac (with .NET MVC)...

Hope this helps you to move forward.

so the dependency injection (service) setup via AutoFac (you could use pure MVC DI):

```
                //
                // Set up HANGFIRE
                var connectionStringName = config["Hangfire:ConnectionStringName"];
                var connectionSection = config.GetSection($"Data:{connectionStringName}");
                var connectionString = config[$"Data:{connectionStringName}:ConnectionString"];

                var queuePollIntervanInMs = int.Parse(config["Hangfire:QueuePollIntervalInMilliseconds"]);

                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseLogProvider(new HangfireLogProvider());
                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(
                    connectionString,
                    new SqlServerStorageOptions() { QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(queuePollIntervanInMs) }
                );

                var serverEnabled = bool.Parse(config["Hangfire:ServerEnabled"]);
                if (serverEnabled)
                {
                    GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new AutomaticRetryAttribute());
                    GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new HangfirePermanentFailureNofitifactionAttribute());

                    // Setting up Hangfire background job processing (use SIGLETON!, keep reference for graceful shutdown - btw. app.UseHangfireServer() works in web-context and does register to graceful-shutdown)
                    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseAutofacActivator(_container);

                    _hangfireServer = new BackgroundJobServer(
                        new BackgroundJobServerOptions()
                        {
                            Activator = JobActivator.Current
                        },
                        JobStorage.Current
                    );
                }
```

startup.cs (configure services - before adding the dependencies above) - ignore some comments, I don't find them useful:

```
                /*
                // Hangfire - since we plan to use it both in web and threaded (unit test) env., initialization is done with hangfire globals on a single place...
                services.AddHangfire(h =>
                {
                    // h.UseSqlServerStorage("<connection string or its name>");
                    // h.UseActivator(...)
                    // h.UseFilter(...)
                });
                */

                // NOTE: the following 2 objects needs to be registered for dashboard to work...https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/129707d66fde24dc6379fb9d6b15fa0b8ca48605/src/Hangfire.AspNetCore/HangfireServiceCollectionExtensions.cs
                services.TryAddSingleton(_ => GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
                services.TryAddSingleton(_ => DashboardRoutes.Routes);
```

and the startup.cs (configure iapp builder:

```
                var dashboardEnabled = bool.Parse(Configuration["Hangfire:DashboardEnabled"]);
                if (dashboardEnabled)
                {
                    // NOTE: Place a call to the UseHangfireDashboard method after other authentication methods in your OWIN Startup class. Otherwise authentication may not work for you.
                    var hangfireDashboarOptions = new DashboardOptions
                    {
                        Authorization = new IDashboardAuthorizationFilter[]
                        {
                            new LocalRequestsOnlyAuthorizationFilter()
                        },
                        StatsPollingInterval = int.Parse(Configuration["Hangfire:DashboardRefreshIntervalInMilliseconds"])
                    };

                    // https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/129707d66fde24dc6379fb9d6b15fa0b8ca48605/src/Hangfire.AspNetCore/HangfireApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs
                    app.UseHangfireDashboard("/dashboard", hangfireDashboarOptions, JobStorage.Current);
                }
```

and a sample on invocation:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Main event handler, can inherit from multiple IDomainEventHandler<TEvent>.
    /// NOTE: depending how event registration and dispatching is done, for each handler a separate instance might be served from the DI framework!
    /// </summary>
    public class UserEventHandler :
        IDomainEventHandler<UserRegisteredEvent>
    {
        private ILog _logger;
        private MyDbContext _myDbContext;

        public UserEventHandler(
            ILog logger,
            MyDbContext myDbContext,
            )
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _myDbContext = myDbContext;
        }

        public void Handle(UserRegisteredEvent e)
        {
            // Send Welcome Email
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.User.Email))
                BackgroundJob.Enqueue<UserMessageHandler>(i => i.SendWelcomeEmail(e.User.Email, e.User.UserName, e.UserPassword, e.PRCo));
            else
                _logger.Warn(new { Message = $"Can't send notification email, user: '{e.User.GetFullName()}' with SSN: {e.User.Ssn}' has no email assigned!" });

            // Send Welcome SMS
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.CellPhone))
                BackgroundJob.Enqueue<UserMessageHandler>(i => i.SendWelcomeSMS(e.CellPhone, e.User.UserName, e.UserPassword));
            else
                _logger.Warn(new { Message = $"Can't send notification message, user: '{e.User.GetFullName()}' with SSN: {e.User.Ssn}' has no cell phone assigned!" });
        }
```

The trick is as you see UserMessageHandler is not injected into the handler class itself, it's injected into the context (as a singleton - but not necessarily as a singleton) and Hangfire is picking up the object from the context!